Do you still need to give old maaser?
If one realized that years ago they earned money and did not give maaser, is there a chiyuv to give the maaser now?

Welcome to MiYodeya Wildin Bochur and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

First of all remember that many poskim rule that the "halachot" of ma'aser are actually time-honored minhagim that should be kept, and not strictly halachot (see e.g., here). As such there is often some flexibility in answering this sort of question. As such it is important to consult a Rav who knows you well.
Now to answer the question, R Yisrael Bronstein (in The halachos of ma'aser kesafim, p. 47) writes

One who never took upon himself to practice ma'aser kesafim and wishes to begin giving ma'aser has no obligation to take ma'aser
from past income. If, however, he had accepted this practice
upon himself, but was not careful in fulfilling it, he should make a
calculation of past income and make sure to give all that he owes! (Shevet Halevi)
Some rule that even one who never practiced giving ma'aser should try
to give ma'aser from past income, if possible. (R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach)
The halachah for one who was in the habit of taking ma'aser but became neglectful and stopped taking it is as follows: If the monies
that should have been separated were used for food and general
expenses, middas chassidus (going beyond what the halachah requires)
obligates one who is able to do so to give ma'aser now (a poor person
is exempt). (Tashbetz) If the money was used to purchase goods which last, then
the halachah obligates both rich and poor to give ma'aser. (Ktzot Hachoshen).

